# Équivalent français de l'expression « eating your own dog food »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

L'expression « eating your own dog food » (ou « dogfooding ») est utilisée pour désigner la pratique qui consiste pour une entreprise, en particulier les éditeurs de logiciels, à utiliser ses propres produits. Le but peut être soit d'avoir des retours plus directs et/ou nombreux sur la qualité des produits, soit de prouver à ses clients la confiance portée à ses propres produits.

Quel équivalent français véhiculerait le sens de cette expression ?

Je cherche quelque chose de plus imagé qu'un simple « utiliser ses propres produits ».

Comment: Il y a une forme d'antithèse : _Les cordonniers sont toujours les plus mal chaussés_ http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/les_cordonniers_sont_toujours_les_plus_mal_chauss%C3%A9s

Answer (score 4):

Ce concept existe bien sur en Francais, souvent utilisé en entreprise industrielle ou BTP : il s'agit de l'**[autoéquipement](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/auto%C3%A9quipement/6689)**.

En comptabilité, on parle de ["livraison à soi-même"](https://www.l-expert-comptable.com/a/37719-saisir-les-ecritures-comptables-liees-aux-immobilisations.html#ancre-1).

https://www.l-expert-comptable.com/a/37719-saisir-les-ecritures-comptables-liees-aux-immobilisations.html#ancre-1

C'est quand même mieux que *dogfooding* !!!

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE.  Il est bon de mettre les exemples/définitions cités directement dans la réponse, pas seulement les liens (qui peuvent changer) pour une réponse complète.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai entendu "goûter sa propre soupe" à quelques occasions.  Sinon, pour ce qui est du "dogfooding", je l'ai entendu à toutes les sauces, pas juste pour les éditeurs de logiciels.

Comment: Votre usage de *sauce*, quelle définition assortit-elle sur http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/sauce/71116?q=sauce#70345 ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de traduction, ni même d'expression française correspondant à *dogfooding* à ma connaissance.

C'est typiquement le type de termes que l'on pourrait employer en anglais dans les entreprises françaises, en l'attente d'un éventuel néologisme. *Marketing* en fait également partie, sa francisation *mercatique* n'ayant jamais connu de succès.

"Que l'on pourrait", car il semble que *dogfooding* [n'est ni très employé](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dogfooding,marketing,mercatique&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) en français, ni [recherché sur internet](http://www.google.fr/trends/explore?q=dogfooding,marketing,mercatique#q=dogfooding,%20marketing,%20mercatique&geo=FR&cmpt=q).

Comment: Pourriez-vous expliciter la signification de "Que l'on pourrait" ?

Comment: @LePressentiment "Que l'on pourrait" fait référence au paragraphe précédent ("que l'on pourrait employer en anglais", et qui implique que l'on ne l'emploie pas).

Answer (score 1):

On entend parfois des formules que l'on peut adapter selon les circonstances :

> "Nos programmes sont aussi (ou sont d'abord) utilisés (ou validés) en interne."

Entendre *eating you own dogfooding* dans une conversation fait à penser à un auditeur non averti que l'on mange la nourriture du chien, que l'on est donc extrêmement pauvre.
Malheureusement certains sont réduits à manger les préparations pour animaux pour obtenir les protéines les moins chères.